# How to make this property LastItemModifiedDate work?

Tags: c#, sharepoint

From SharePoint 2003 to 2013 there is a property **LastItemModifiedDate** in SPWeb class which is used with a method **GetSubwebsForCurrentUser()**, which also belongs to the SPWeb class. I tried a lot to make it work but I failed. See this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd586994(v=office.11).aspx for descriptions. All version same thing. Can anyone give some guide to show how to use this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: Nobody knows the answer? Looks like it's a tough and rare one.